# How to ADD OR REMOVE spring framework's scheduler dynamically(server in running status) with DB data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oracle-sqldeveloper, spring-scheduled

I am working with Spring-boot and Oracle sql developer.
I want to implement something like 'user administrating scheduler'.

User can add or remove scheduler on web page.
If user adds 'scheduler running every 3 minutes', db table may be...

```
s_id | s_cron | s_detail
sid000001 | 0 0/3 * * * ? | do job 1
```

and spring scheduler must do 'job 1' in every 3 minutes.

And if, another user also adds 'scheduler running every 1 minutes',

```
s_id | s_cron | s_detail
sid000001 | 0 0/3 * * * ? | do job 1
sid000002 | 0 0/1 * * * ? | do job 2
```

and spring scheduler must do 'job 1' in every 3 minutes, and must do 'job 2' in every 1 minutes simultaneously.

**The problem is : how can I make it in Spring-boot?
Spring service must add/remove dynamically(or automatically) scheduler with db data added/removed in server running.**

Please give me some hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically schedule tasks you can do it without spring by using **ExecutorService** in particular **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor**

```
Runnable task  = () -> doSomething();
ScheduledExecutorService executor = 
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
// Schedule a task that will be executed in 120 sec
executor.schedule(task, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// Schedule a task that will be first run in 120 sec and each 120sec
// If an exception occurs then it's task executions are canceled.
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 120, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// Schedule a task that will be first run in 120 sec and each 120sec after 
the last 
execution
// If an exception occurs then it's task executions are canceled.
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 120, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```